# Validate form as the user progresses (not only on submit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a registration form for my application and want to be able to validate fields on change. For example, I'd like to be able to immediately validate password complexity before hitting submit. In my code below, this only occurs after hitting submit.

I'd like to do a similar thing for the `email` field, but I cant seem to work out how to do this for a single element, without validating the whole form.

My HTML form:

```
<form class="needs-validation" id="registration-form" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md mb-3 mx-auto">
            <label for="firstName">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="" value="" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Required.
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md mb-3 mx-auto">
            <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Required.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md mb-3 mx-auto">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Email required.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md mb-3 mx-auto">
            <label for="password">Create a password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" pattern="(?=.*)\S{6,}" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter a valid password for your account. Password must be at least 6 characters in length.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md mb-3 mx-auto">
            <label for="confirm-password">Confirm password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm-password" required>
            <div id="confirm-password-invalid-feedback" class="invalid-feedback">
                Please confirm your password.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md mb-3 mx-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Create My Account</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Javascript is as follows, in `validation.js`

```
(function() {
'use strict';

///...

$("form").submit(function(e){
    //register();
    if ($("form")[0].checkValidity() === false) {
        console.log('validation failed');
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    else {
        console.log('calling posting now');
        posting();
        event.preventDefault();            
    }
});

var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
var password = document.getElementById('password'), confirm_password = document.getElementById('confirm-password');

function validatePassword() {
    if(password.value != confirm_password.value) {
        //there is no boolean var to set validity to invalid
        //password.setCustomValidity('invalid');
        confirm_password.setCustomValidity('invalid');

        if (confirm_password.value != '') {
            document.getElementById('confirm-password-invalid-feedback').textContent = 'The passwords do not match.';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('confirm-password-invalid-feedback').textContent = 'Confirm your password.';
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    else {
        password.setCustomValidity(''); //reset validity to valid

        if (password.validity.valid == false) {
            document.getElementById('confirm-password-invalid-feedback').textContent = 'Please confirm your password.';
        }
        else {
            confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    //fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    //loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            validatePassword();

            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }

            form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
    });

    password.onchange = validatePassword;
    confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
}, false);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function on change

```
$('form').change(function() {
    // code
})
```

You could also do this:

```
$('form').keydown(function() {
    // code
})
```

This would be live.

Comment: But how do I make the field highlight and display the `.invalid-feedback` section, and trigger the browser's invalid state?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$("input.email").change(function(){
    // Add the verification logic for that particular input (validation function?)
});
```

Comment: But how do I make the field highlight and display the `.invalid-feedback` section, and trigger the browser's invalid state?

Comment: By appending to the input a div with a class `.invalid-feedback` (http://api.jquery.com/append/) and then adding the error text to that class (http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to validate fields before submitting the form, you'll have to set up event listener on change for the form and handle validation inside it. For example, if you want to validate the password, you can put your password validation function inside the form change function like so:

```
$("form").change(function(){
    validatePassword();
});
```

Comment: But how do I make the field highlight and display the `.invalid-feedback` section, and trigger the browser's invalid state?

Comment: The same way confirm-password is being done right now. In the validatePassword function you can reuse the same logic and use the "invalid-feedback" ID instead. Basically, the whole chunk of password validation is missing from your code right now.